# Data Standarisation of a list of list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want a standardized list of lists. I have the main list

```
Data=[[5, 3, 2, 8, 5, 10, 8, 1, 2],
 [5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [8, 10, 3, 2, 6, 4, 3, 10, 1]]
```

I have calculated the list of column averages and a list of Standard Deviation for 9 columns.

```
col_avg=[4.47,3.14,3.10,2.67, 3.25,3.83,3.16,2.99, 1.60]
col_std=[2.86,2.98,2.77,2.76,2.13,3.77,2.17, 3.16,1.67]
```

Now I want a list of lists where the elements are standardized.
The formula: (x-col_avg)/col_std

I don't want to use any python packages like Pandas and Numpy. It should be in general python.

Answer (score 0):

You could do so with nested list comprehension, in combination with `enumerate`.

```
[[(e - col_avg[i]) / col_std[i] for i, e in enumerate(line)] for line in Data]
```

Basically you loop over `Data`, for each line you loop over the elements together with the index (from `enumerate`). With this index you can then 'lookup' the relevant avg and std values.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of reiterating what @ScootCork said, I had the same solution, although using an outer for loop. The function `enumerate` gets the index for every element, which is used to look up the column in your pre-computed lists.

```
out = []
for i, col in enumerate(Data):
    standardized_col = [(x - col_avg[i]) / col_std[i] for x in col]
    out.append(standardized_col)

print(out)
```